# Remove blue border from open <details> element in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-tag-details

I'm upgrading my site to use the new HTML5 `details` element for better accessibility.

It's all working OK, but unfortunately when I click to open the element, Chrome applies an ugly blue border:

[image]

Is there any way I can stop Chrome doing this? I can't see any explicit CSS styles being applied, so I'm not sure how to get rid of it.

JSFiddle code here to demo the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/6x2Kc/

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use `outline:none;`

**For Instance,**

```
summary{
  outline:none;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6x2Kc/3/)**

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually setting outline:none on **all** HTML elements as in the comment of @SurjithSM is a really bad practise, as users who use the tab button to tab through controls wont see what is focused. Also disabled persons will have problems using such a website.

Comment: Even just this answer is not great for accessibility, how will a user know after tabbing through the page whether summary is focussed or not?

Answer (score 4):

Use outline: 0;

```
summary:focus {
     outline: 0;
}
```